# making googledrive as storage for the images of my website carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-api, carousel

I am thinking of making googledrive as storage for my images in the bootstrap carousel of my website. I am also thinking of this as advantage:

- I can easily manage the changes between the images of my website by locating googledrive and manipulate it.
- Storage space advantage.

Is it possible to make the googledrive as storage images for my carousel? not only as a storage, in fact the most likely i was thinking is about manipulating the images of the carousel dynamically and easily by manipulating it in googledrive. Please anyone can help me how to do this ?. or maybe possible ?

Comment: Hoping this helps https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java#Photos

Comment: thank you for your answer sir. Its great but i need for PHP version. is there?

Comment: Look at this https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php. But its older version also I haven't tried this, so can't tell about the extent of feasibility of the operations you intend to perform

Comment: is there any other soluton. so hard to implement and yet not tested .. :'(